# Miktex suddenly stopped compiling

Tags: latex, miktex

Anyone know what I can do? It says

> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

It tells me to check logs, the logs have this:

```
2017-11-07 09:24:39,753+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:24:39,775+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-11-07 09:24:49,540+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:24:49,558+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-11-07 09:27:05,405+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:30:33,755+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:42:15,598+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:43:32,265+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:44:47,048+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:45:48,616+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:46:03,037+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:46:32,470+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:47:20,975+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:48:30,388+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:49:46,624+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:50:18,021+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:50:46,415+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:52:06,725+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:53:55,610+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:54:59,092+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 09:55:10,054+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 10:15:47,798+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 10:16:25,107+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 10:17:21,929+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 10:18:43,648+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 10:19:06,740+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: 
2017-11-07 10:19:26,582+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a ton of troubleshooting I found out that, if you use `\makebibliography{}` and do not cite anything, LaTeX will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had a small syntax error. Instead of cite[Ch XX]{XX} I had written cite{Ch XX[XX]}. Check your syntax.

Answer (score -3):

If you create a new tex file and paste your latex code inside, it should work.